# BizTalk ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: oracle, wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I am having issue with the new TNS connection. I have added the below code in to the tnsnames.ora file. I can verify the connection using the SQL Oracle developer, it is perfect.

```
c0xlxx =
 (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS_LIST =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxxxxxxx)(PORT=xxxxxxxxx))
  )
  (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVICE_NAME = xxxxxxx )
  )
 )
```

I did the sameway in the BizTalk application dev environment, it is working perfectly.But when I use in the BizTalk application in test environment using WCF-Custom adapter for OracleDBBinding with URI oracledb://c0xlxx/ it is throwing error
`The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port "WcfSendPort_LTMDBBindingtoAX_View_VW_JOB_DEPT_Custom" with URL "oracledb://c0xlxx/". It will be retransmitted after the retry interval specified for this Send Port. Details:"Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.ConnectionException: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified ---> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified` Help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have some diferent properties to conection strings on TNS, you must need to seek the correct for your situation Example:

xxxxxx =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxx)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = xxxx)
      (SID = xxxx)
    )
  )

Can you send a properties who you entered to connect in SQL Oracle developer. Are you sure if you connect over TNS protocol in SQL Oracle developer

Try tnsping on windows cmd, command tnsping servername yours is c0xlxx. This command look like a ping, but its for oracle db server ping